# Two models and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

In general there are two models of Content (name, desc, etc ...) and Files (id_content, file) Content (has_many: files) Files (belongs_to: content). That is, the class itself should work with the upload file field model, Files, and infa file must be entered in the Content. Please show me how some would look create action in such a situation and form. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To the File model you add this:

```
mount_uploader :file, YourFileUploader
```

In the view you should add: (if you use simple_form and haml/slim)

```
= f.simple_fields_for :files do |file|
  = file.input_field :file
  = file.input_field :file
  = file.input_field :file
  = file.input_field :file
```

you can add only one input_field if you want.